# Generate docx documents from a docx template javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, docx

I am looking for a library in `javascript` that can generate `docx` documents from a `docx` template  and can replace tags by their values and replace images with other images I found a library name `DocxTemplater` but it's for `nodjs` and work on server side I want to this in browser side and with `javascript`.
Is there any library in javascript that able to do this???

Answer (score 1):

[DocxTemplater](https://github.com/edi9999/docxtemplater) can be built to use from the browser directly, as detailed [here](http://docxtemplater.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#browser).

If you aren't comfortable getting those utilities up and running on your local machine you can always get a free account somewhere like [Nitrous](http://www.nitrous.io) and use a Node box there.